# MySql queries takes long to finish

Tags: mysql, database, logic

I have a classic ASP page in which I have all my clients(about 4,000),active or not, and I need to get information on them in 4 different tables. The way I'm currently doing it, my page takes 3,4,5 minutes depending on how busy the server is also.Sometimes I even get the message in asp that says "The maximum amount of time for a script to execute was exceeded".
My queries are as follow,
1. I get my clients personal info
2. I get my clients sales
3. after having that info, I do a for loop of my clients array to get other information.
   In that loop I make 5 different queries.

All the information I get is necessary in my page.
What would be the best method to do all of this ?

### (I was looking into views,triggers,functions/procedures)

Queries (in FRENCH):
1.

```
SELECT c.NoClient, c.NomClient, c.CodeClient, c.NoClientFront,c.NoVendeur,
c.VilleClient,c.DateOuverture",Telemarketing,Autre1 FROM Client c WHERE (left(c.CodeClient,1) = 'C' Or left(c.CodeClient,1) = 'N') ORDER BY c.NoClient



CREATE TABLE `client` (
  `NoClient` decimal(7,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `NoVendeur` decimal(3,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `NomClient` varchar(35) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `AdresseClient` varchar(35) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `VilleClient` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `TelClient` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `CodeClient` char(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `PointPower` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `PrevisionYonka` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `PrevisionCollin` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `TerritoireClient` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `NoClientFront` int(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `PersonneContact` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `CodeCredit` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `CodePostalClient` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `DateOuverture` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `Master` int(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Telemarketing` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `GammeAutorisee1` char(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `GammeAutorisee2` char(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `GammeAutorisee3` char(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `GammeAutorisee4` char(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `GammeAutorisee5` char(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `MembrePower` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `NoteLivreur1` varchar(35) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `NoteLivreur2` varchar(35) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `PlanAVenirYonka` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `PlanAVenirCollin` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Autre1` varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Langue du client',
  `Autre2` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `NoteClient` text NOT NULL,
  `CompteInternet` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `DEI` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Empty1` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `Empty2` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`NoClient`),
  KEY `CodeClient` (`CodeClient`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

2.

```
Select a.NoClient,a.Gamme,a.Vente,a.Annee,a.Mois,c.Dateouverture" from AchatClient a, Client c where c.NoClient = a.NoClient And a.Annee <= " & AnneeRanking
And a.Annee >= " & AnneeRanking - 1 order by a.NoClient

CREATE TABLE `achatclient` (
  `NoClient` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NoVendeur` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Gamme` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `G1` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `G2` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Annee` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Mois` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Vente` float(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `NoClient` (`NoClient`,`NoVendeur`),
  KEY `Vente` (`NoClient`,`Annee`,`Mois`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**in my FOR loop**
a)

```
Select DatePlanification from planification where NoClient=" & client(i) 
And DatePlanification <= '" & todayDate & "' And Etat=0 Order by DatePlanification DESC limit 1 

CREATE TABLE `planification` (
  `NoPlanification` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `IDUsager` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NoClient` decimal(7,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DatePlanification` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `HeurePlanDebut` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `HeurePlanFin` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `LieuxPlanification` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `TypePlanification` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `NomPlanification` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Commentaire` text NOT NULL,
  `Confirmation` int(1) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `TypeContact` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `GammeContact` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `DetailPersonnel` text NOT NULL,
  `DetailPublic` text NOT NULL,
  `DateEntree` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `HeureEntree` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `DateModifie` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `HeureModifie` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `Autre1` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Autre2` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Etat` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `DateCheckIn` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TimeCheckIn` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PositionCheckIn` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DateCheckOut` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TimeCheckOut` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PositionCheckOut` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Empty1` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Empty2` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`NoPlanification`),
  KEY `IDUsager` (`IDUsager`,`DatePlanification`),
  KEY `DatePlanification` (`DatePlanification`),
  KEY `NoClient` (`NoClient`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

b)

```
Select DateVisite from visite_kterm where NoClient = " & Client(i)
order by DateVisite DESC limit 1
CREATE TABLE `visite_kterm` (
  `NoClient` int(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DateVisite` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `SequenceVisite` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Usager` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Description_1` varchar(72) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Description_2` varchar(72) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Description_3` varchar(72) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Description_4` varchar(72) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Description_5` varchar(72) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Description_6` varchar(72) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Description_7` varchar(72) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `NoClient` (`NoClient`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

C)

```
Select DatePlanification from Planification where NoClient=" & Client(i) 
And DatePlanification > '" & answerFromA & "' And Etat=0
Order by DatePlanification ASC limit 1;
```

d)`SELECT DateFacture FROM listefactures where NoClient=" & client(i)`

```
CREATE TABLE `listefactures` (
  `NoFacture` varchar(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `NoPrise` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NoClient` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PrisePar` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DateFacture` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `AdresseEnvoie` text,
  `Reference` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SousTotal` float(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Total` float(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Terme` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TaxePro` float(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TaxeFed` float(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Transporteur` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FraisTransport` float(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FraisManutention` float(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Ouverture` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FacturePower` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CodeCredit` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `RepOuverture` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`NoFacture`),
  KEY `NoClient` (`NoClient`,`Ouverture`),
  KEY `NoPrise` (`NoPrise`),
  KEY `DateFacture` (`DateFacture`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

e)

```
Select Email from SDS where NoCompte = " & Client(i) 
And Email like '%@%' And Email like '%.%';
CREATE TABLE `sds` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NoCompte` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SiteWeb` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NomProprietaire` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ageproprietaire` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `StatutProprietaire` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NomProprietaireDuLocataire` text,
  `Localisation` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Situation` varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ProprioEstEstheticienne` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Travailencabine` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ProprioDepuis` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `NomPersonneContact` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FonctionPersonneContact` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NbEstheticienne` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NbEmploye` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NbCabineFacial` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NbCabineCorporel` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NbCabineAutre` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NbCabineDouche` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NbCabineBain` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `NbCabineLitSolaire` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SoinsOfferts` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Competition1` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Competition2` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Competition3` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Competition4` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Competition5` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PotentielClient` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EtatVitrine` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EtatComptoireVitre` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EtatEtalageMur` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SurfaceIncitante` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PopulationVille` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NbCliniqueExistante` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NbCliniqueNotre` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ParticulariteVille` text NOT NULL,
  `DateMAJ` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Email1` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Contact1` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `titre1` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Email2` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Contact2` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `titre2` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Email3` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Contact3` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `titre3` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Email4` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Contact4` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `titre4` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `statutProspect` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `dei` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `deivalue` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`,`NoCompte`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=7356 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: It sounds like you need to do a join.  If done correctly, that query should take less than one second.  Please post the queries you are using.

Comment: 1. Post the queries. 2. Post an `EXPLAIN` of each query.

Comment: I have tried join tables but it does not make any difference.

Comment: Please post the queries you're running.  It sounds like your tables aren't indexed.

Comment: "I was looking into views,triggers,functions/procedures"  Those options would not be much faster if the underlying queries are the same.  Can you please also post the structure of the tables?

Comment: *"I have a classic ASP page in which I have all my clients(about 4,000),active or not ... I do a for loop of my clients array to get other information. In that loop I make 5 different queries."* So you are running approximately 20 000 consecutive queries? No wonder your page takes a long time to finish!

Comment: I know, sounds dumb to do that but I haven't found a proper way.That's why I was asking here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I combined all of your queries into one.  I made a few assumptions like that you only want one record per client.  Variables that need to be added are in curly braces.

```
SELECT NoClient, Gamme, Vente, Annee, Mois, Dateouverture, NomClient, CodeClient,
    NoClientFront, NoVendeur, VilleClient, DateOuverture, Telemarketing, Autre1,
    MAX(DatePlanification) AS DatePlanification, MAX(DateVisite ) AS DateVisite, Email
FROM Client
    JOIN AchatClient USING (NoClient)
    JOIN planification USING (NoClient)
    JOIN visite_kterm USING (NoClient)
    JOIN DateFacture USING (NoClient)
    LEFT JOIN SDS ON (NoClient = NoCompte)
WHERE (CodeClient LIKE 'C%' OR CodeClient LIKE 'N%')
    AND Annee BETWEEN {AnneeRanking} AND {AnneeRanking - 1}
    AND DatePlanification <= {todayDate}
    AND Etat=0
    AND Email like '%@%' AND Email like '%.%'
GROUP BY NoClient
ORDER BY NoClient
```

The query would benefit from indexes as listed below:

```
SDS - single index on `NoCompte`
planification - make the `NoClient` index composite like (`NoClient`, `DatePlanification`)
achatclient - single index on `Annee`
```

Also, make all of the `NoClient` columns  one of the `INT` types.

Using a single query like this should be *much* faster than tons of serial queries.  You might need to switch some of the `JOIN`s to `LEFT JOIN`s depending on the data.

Comment: I've been playing around with your query and I was able to Query the client table with 3 left joins on AchatClient,sds,geocode but when I add any of the other ones (planification,visite_kterm,listeFactures) it takes very long. In the GROUP BY NoClient I changed it to GROUP BY NoClient,Annee,Gamme. Any idea why?

Comment: Post an `EXPLAIN` of the query; it will help diagnose the problem.

Comment: Didn't know how to upload and image directly to SO so here's a lingk with a screenshot. [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/kgt7R.png)

Comment: Post the `EXPLAIN` of the query with all of the joins that takes a while.

Comment: The query actually never finishes.Here is the image of the explain results [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/cyWip.png)

Comment: Add the indexes that I mention at the bottom of my answer.  The one you really need is the last one, but the others can be helpful.  Right now, it's having to scan all of `achatclient`, which is causing most of the problem.  Adding the index on `Annee` will help immensely.

Comment: I added the index on Annee in the achatClient table and I still get 86,794 rows. The I added a composite index on (noclient,annee) and still get the 86,794 rows.